# Is it possible to speed up a video using handbrake?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, playback

Is it possible to speed up a video using handbrake ?

I am looking for a software like handbrake to convert videos for faster playback. It should speed up the video up to 30x.

Is it possible with handbrake or are there similar tools ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), a free command-line tool, to do this.

The basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/30" -crf 18 output.mov
```

The `30` indicates the factor by which the video will be sped up.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This helps mutch. Is there propably also a way to revirse a video with ffmpeg ?

Comment: Sure. but it loads the whole file into memory, so I suggest applying it after speed change, like this: `-vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/30,reverse"`

Comment: Note, this seems to add a bunch of empty blackness at the end. Or, rather, it condenses the video but keeps the original length and just fills it with solid black.

Comment: If you have an audio track in the input which isn't correspondingly sped up, yes, but not otherwise. Add `-an` to disable or `-af atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=2,atempo=1.875` to speed up the audio as well.

Comment: If you do keep audio (without speed up), whether it's black depends on the player's behaviour. In Potplayer, the last frame is frozen.

Comment: @Mulvya What's the relation between video speed up factor of 30 and audio tempo speed up of 1.875? Basically I just want to speed up a video 4 times, what should be the arguments for audio speed up in that case?

Comment: Audio is sped up using the atempo filter, which only takes values in the range of [0.5-2]. So to make a speed change outside that range, multiple atempo filters have to be daisychained. I have four filters with value of 2 and 1 of 1.875 since `2*2*2*2*1.875=30`. For four times, you need `atempo=2,atempo=2`

Comment: What is crf 18?

Comment: Constant rate factor - in practice, a measure of the quality/size tradeoff used by the default video encoder (x264) for MP4 and MOVs. Lower is better but bigger. 18 is good; 23 is default.

Answer (score 6):

Using FFmpeg's command-line, this is totally possible. I do it to increase the speed of my videos by 10% (increasing both the audio AND video by 10%, without sounding like a chipmunk).

The command to increase your video's speed by 10% is:

```
<ffmpeg path> -i <origin video path> -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.1" -crf 18 -af atempo=1.1 <output video path>
```

Here's the exact command line that I use:

```
"C:\Program Files\ffmpeg-win64\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i "G:\minecraft lets play.mp4" -vf "setpts=(PTS-STARTPTS)/1.1" -crf 18 -af atempo=1.1 "G:\minecraft lets play ffmpeg.mp4"
```

If you want to increase your video's speed by more, or less, then you just change the "1.1" at both lines to something else. "1.1" is 10%. "1.5" is 50%. "3" is 300%. "10" is 1000%.

Comment: great answer! as you mention audio, cheers!